# Does anyone know how to make a custom search in Bugzilla?

Tags: bug-tracking, bugzilla

I'm trying to make a search in Bugzilla which is used during our evaluation. The search basically lists how many defects were logged by each employee. Does anyone know how we can do this in Bugzilla?

(The advanced search page has options for "Advanced Searching Using Boolean Charts: ". I think it could probably be using that? )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Bugzilla 3.4.4 use a tabular report and select "Reporter" for the vertical axis and any other filter conditions and you will get the count of bug filed by login.

Comment: Excellent answer. I'm now able to see the required data. Thanks a load.

Comment: Hi Wayne, could you please help regarding [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75877271/how-to-change-deskzilla-default-attachment-download-location) ?